# weka SVM multi class classifier

Tags: weka, svm, libsvm

I understand that weka use a 1 to 1 approach in terms of SVM. However, i would like to classify documents and i have 10 class labels.

Is it possible to change the parameters to change it to a 1 vs rest approach instead.

How should i actually go about doing it.

The official site http://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM does not help much

Other classification methods such as naive bayes have been tried but i would like to compare the results against SVM methods

Answer (score 0):

LIBSVM also allows multi-label classification. You can find here examples of implementation.
http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/multilabel/

You can also search papers that using LibSVM with non-binary datasets. 
i.e. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00521-011-0793-1

Anyway another variant to use LibSVM is SMO WEKA library.

Answer (score 0):

In Weka Version 3.8, the multi-class meta classifier can be used. It also has options including 1-against-1 and 1-against-all multi-classification methods.